# Regular Expressions - String between 2 Strings which have symbols in it

Tags: regex

I want to get following content out of the search string

```
searchstring = URL:<br/>https://example.com/welcome?code=3Dhe58e21ae1d160d1.53418445<br/>If you prefer

stringoutput = https://example.com/welcome?code=3Dhe58e21ae1d160d1.53418445
```

I tried to use `(.*?)` but it said that I have to close the /.

Can anyone help me? I'm stuck hard at this point

Answer (score 0):

```
URL:<br\/>(.*)<br\/>.*
```